# python command line ok in python shell but not through windows cmd

Tags: python, windows, printing, cmd, syntax-error

I was about to test the ftpmirror builtin script (python322, winXP 32bits) from the cmd windows default shell and get this :

```
File "C:\Program Files\python322\Tools\Scripts\ftpmirror.py", line 161
print('Skip pattern', repr(pat), end=' ')
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tested the print() line directly in the python shell, trough cmd, and with idle (and in blender also) : this work obsiously.

I reproduce the error with a coucou.py file like this :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
pat = 'toto'
print("Skip pattern", repr(pat), end=" ")
```

when directly called from a cmd prompt :

```
C:\Program Files\python322\Tools\Scripts>coucou.py
```

same error than with ftpmirror
but :

```
C:\Program Files\python322\Tools\Scripts>python coucou.py
```

is ok

and my environment is ok I can execute py scripts directly from the windows ui by double-clicking a .py file, and I got working scripts working fine when called from .bat

I don't get it, it looks specific to the print() end argument, what did I not read yet about the way to execute python3 from the windows cmd shell ?

thanks,

Jerome

Comment: Do you also have Python 2.x installed on your computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking if you are running the same python interpreter when you double click or you run `python` from the command-line.

Save this in a `.py` file with this content and try running it with both methods:

```
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

I bet you are using different interpreters in each case.

Comment: omg... many thanks... sorry...
    PYTHONPATH=C:\Progra~1\python322\;C:\Progra~1\python266
my system is a mess :)

Comment: 'open with...' on the py file REFUSES to let me choose python322 because of a dummy case (266/python.exe and 322/python.exe share the same name.) so I edited directly the registry and replaced any reference to the 266 path in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File by the 322 path. it looks ok now.

if you want to be able to select between different python versions using 'open with' when right-clicking on a py file, one can duplicate each python.exe and rename to python266.exe, python272.exe 322 etc and then choose them when configuring 'open with'(alternatively I bet one can also read the python doc?)